# Apache Pig - How to extract sets of records

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm new user in Apache Pig, I have below data

```
order=0012,1,23  
order=0013,2,34,0015,1,45  
order=0011,1,456
...
```

I tried to extract to below records

```
0012,1,23
0013,2,34
0015,1,45
0011,1,456
...
```

Below are code that I've tried

```
a = LOAD 'a.txt' Using TextLoader() AS (line:chararray);  
b = FOREACH a GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line, 'order=((\\d+),(\\d+),(\\d+))+')) AS
(
    order_item:chararray,
    order_pid: chararray,
    order_qty: chararray,
    order_price: chararray
);
```

It doesn't work.
Another tried by save into Bag:

```
a = LOAD 'a.txt' Using TextLoader() AS (line:chararray);  
b = FOREACH a GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line, 'order=((\\d+),(\\d+),(\\d+))+')) AS
(
    B: bag { T: tuple(
    order_pid: chararray,
    order_qty: chararray,
    order_price: char array
    )}
);
```

Still doesn't work.

Comment: Hi jurgemaister,  Thanks for your reminding, sorry that I'm also new to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

**input:**

```
order=0012,1,23
order=0013,2,34,0015,1,45
order=0011,1,456
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(REGEX_EXTRACT(line,'order=(.*)',1),','));
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(TOBAG(TOTUPLE($0..$2),TOTUPLE($3..$5)));
D = FILTER C BY $0 is not null;
DUMP D;
```

**Output:**

```
(0012,1,23)
(0013,2,34)
(0015,1,45)
(0011,1,456)
```

Comment: I tried and it worked for above sample.  However, is it possible to make it more general, say, if I don't know how many (item, qty, price) after order=?

Comment: If you don't know how many items in upfront then it will be difficult to solve this problem using native pig.You have to go for Custom UDF.   http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/udf.html